# How to add scope query in Laravel scout to retrieve record in model

Tags: laravel, laravel-scout

I have a model Post has method scope:

```
public function scopeABC($query) {
    return $query->where('status', 'publish') //
}
```

And I want to after search by Laravel Scout, the results of Post will apply this scope

```
$posts = Post::searchable('zzzzz')->ABC()->paginate();
```

But Laravel fire exception Laravel\Scout\Builder has not method ABC. Hope you help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

It's not documented feature but you can pass a callback to `query` method
https://github.com/matchish/laravel-scout-elasticsearch/issues/18#issuecomment-505977823

```
$posts = Post::searchable('zzzzz')->query(function($query) {
    return $query->ABC();
})->paginate();
```

Comment: I'm using your package but unfortunately scoped methods seem to have no effect.

Comment: It's not the package specific feature

Comment: Don't do this. It has side effects during a pagination. From Laravel documentation: "Since this callback is invoked after the relevant models have already been retrieved from your application's search engine, the query method should not be used for "filtering" results. Instead, you should use Scout where clauses."

Answer (score -1):

I cannot find solution for you but i think your searchable(() cannot working with paginate(), your problem is not from scope function

Comment: Answers should be helpful and informative. This is neither.